# How does one properly use the verb gustar?

Tags: gramática

I am mostly confused about when to use le or les and gusta or gustan.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Spanish.SE. If you type "gustar" in the search box, you'll see there are already several questions on the topic. Please check them out and if you still have any specific doubt update your question accordingly. Otherwise, your question might be closed.

Answer (score -2):

Whe you say `¿gustan chocolate?` you are offering chocolat
When you say `a ellos les gustan las fiestas` you are explaining that they like to party. It depends of the context